# Javascript formatting xml error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to render xml on a dialog box on success of a ajax call.
But there formatting gets messed up after using the below code.
I see un-neccessary blank spaces in each line. can someone help.

```
success: function (data) {
              $("<div id='xmlmessageHolder'></div>").dialog({
                 title : "View",
                 width: 400,
                 height :500,                
                 open:function(event){
                     $(this).html("<pre>"+escapeHTML(data)+"</pre>");

            } });
        },
```

Comment: what does `escapeHTML` do? what is an (minimal) example of `data` that exhibits the problem you are having?

Comment: @fiddle ok check updated answer you can use vk beautify.

Comment: @owaishanif786 - why are you telling me this? I don't care

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry my badness accidently mentioned you. :)

Comment: I still don't care (kidding now)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove `pre` tag.
you can also use [vkbeautify](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/).

```
success: function (data) {
              $("<div id='xmlmessageHolder'></div>").dialog({
                 title : "View",
                 width: 400,
                 height :500,                
                 open:function(event){

                     $(this).html( vkbeautify.xml(escapeHTML(data)) );

            } });
        },
```

Comment: This messes up the xml even more.